# Separate Implementation in own files in same package

Tags: go

I am try to get hands dirty with golang. So I invented a small project and want do build a small console app with different commands.

I found [codegangsta/cli](https://github.com/codegangsta/cli) and tried the example.

```
    package main

import (
    "os"


    "github.com/codegangsta/cli"
)
func main() {
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Commands = []cli.Command{
        {
            Name:      "add",
            Usage:     "add a task to the list",
            Action: func(c *cli.Context) {
                println("added task: ", c.Args().First())
            },
        },
        {
            Name:      "complete",
            Usage:     "complete a task on the list",
            Action: func(c *cli.Context) {
                println("completed task: ", c.Args().First())
            },
        },

    }
    app.Run(os.Args)
}
```

Now I want to put the commands in Commands-array in separate files and only reference them.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for some advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way of several ways to split the file up:

In file main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "github.com/codegangsta/cli"
)

func main() {
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Commands = []cli.Command{
        addCommand,
        completeCommand,
    }
    app.Run(os.Args)
}
```

In file comamnds.go write:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/codegangsta/cli"
)

var addCommand = cli.Command{
        Name:      "add",
        Usage:     "add a task to the list",
        Action: func(c *cli.Context) {
            println("added task: ", c.Args().First())
        },
    }

 var completeCommand cli.Command{
        Name:      "complete",
        Usage:     "complete a task on the list",
        Action: func(c *cli.Context) {
            println("completed task: ", c.Args().First())
        },
    }
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. I take things a step further usually and (using a CLI package or not..) split every high level command into its own file with its children. This keeps the files focused and doesn't cause too much bloat.

Comment: Thanks a lot ThunderCat. This works!. But why is it important to name the first file main.go? When it has an other name it does't.work. The variables then can not be resolved.